# How to loop through rows in VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to loop through a lot of data—5,734 rows to be exact. This is what I want to do for all rows:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

Range("A2:A14").Copy Range("D2:D14")
("B2:B14").Copy Range("D15:D27")
Range("C2:C14").Copy Range("D28:D40")
```

Comment: If you intend to copy only these specific ranges, why do you need to iterate? Where the 5734 rows should be in your code? Maybe, instead of code, it would be good to better explain what you really want to accomplish... When you copy a range, it would be enough to specify only the range/cell where to be pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data looks like this (colour to show more easily the groups):

[image]

The following code will paste each group (yellow, green) to the "Result" column.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copy_paste()

Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set the name of the sheet

lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row in column A

For i = 2 To lrow Step 13 'Loop every group (group of 13 rows) in column A
    For j = 1 To 13 Step 13 'For each group, copy and paste
        ws.Cells(i, "A").Resize(13).Copy ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'Copy the group and paste it to the column D. Offset by one to not overwrite the last row
        ws.Cells(i, "B").Resize(13).Copy ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ws.Cells(i, "C").Resize(13).Copy ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Glad to help! :), Feel free to mark the question as solved (grey tickbox under the voting buttons) so other people can see the issue is solved. Happy coding.